# Как вставить картинку в Tkinter через Pillow (PIL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, изображения, pillow

Как вставить картинку в Tkinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде чем мы напишем код мы должны установить PIL (Pillow)

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

В коде есть все подробности - смотрим и разбираемся.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW # Импортируем Tkinter модули
from PIL import Image, ImageTk # Импортируем Pillow


class Images(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI() # Делаем оболочку

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Заголовок окна") # Заголовок окна
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.img = Image.open("tatras.png") # В кавычках вписать название файла или полный путь
        self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img) # Вставляем изображение

        canvas = Canvas( # Делаем доску для вставления изображения и прописываем необходимые атрибуты
            self, width=self.img.size[0] + 20,
            height=self.img.size[1] + 20
        )

        canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras) # Создание изображения на холсте (доске)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) # Тип Canvas (т.е. как она будет вставлена, размер и т.д.)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Images()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @insolor будем честны, здесь довольно простой код для написания, если захочу тоже сделаю про tkinter.