# Почему tkinter не видит изображение?

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему tkinter не видит изображение? Первоначально я поставил одно изображение и у меня все работало , но затем поменял.

```
# Здесь у меня как выглядит вставка изображения

photo = PhotoImage(file="bg.png")

canvas = Canvas(root,width=250, height=55)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=photo)
canvas.pack(side=TOP, padx=1, pady=1)
```

А это текст ошибки:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bertr\OneDrive\Desktop\RaiderLab Cllient\Scripts\MailSpam\mail.py", line 
35, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="bg.png")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "bg.png"
```

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, видит, но не может прочитать. Возможно тип файла не не соответствует расширению. Например, это не png на самом деле, а какой-нибудь переименованный pdf.

Comment: @insolor я проверил расширение, а также ради эксперимента скачал .png файл с сайта с иконками. Как результат у меня все равно ничего не работает

Comment: "все равно ничего не работает" не дает никакой информации. PhotoImage из PIL берете или стандартный из tkinter?

Comment: Вообще, лучше [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в вопросе приводить вместе со всеми импортами, чтобы не приходилось гадать, какой именно PhotoImage используется.

Comment: По тексту ошибки похоже, что стандартный. Используйте PIL (pip install pillow), как во втором примере в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767829/1365

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить картинку в Tkinter через Pillow (PIL)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1423308/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код который у меня работал, и есть несколько отличий от вашего:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

# Defining the image

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("download.png"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)

my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Используя Image.open вы сможете открыть эту картинку